# installing php_printer on wamp server

Tags: php, wampserver

Ive been googling around on how to install the `php_printer.dll` for wamp server, nothing came up. Perhaps, anyone know how to install that ext? Basically, im trying to use php `printer` function and i need that extension as i heard. i tried http://www.issociate.de/board/goto/751941/Call_to_undefined_function_printer_open().html to install on wamp server, but still give me error in the webpage? i added the `extension: php_printer.dll` in php.ini

```
testing code:
<?php
$filename = "test page";
///////
ob_start();
include $filename;
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
///////
$handle = printer_open("HP80AA62");
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "raw"); 
printer_write($handle,$contents);
printer_close($handle);
?>
```

Comment: Does `phpinfo()` show the extension loaded?

Comment: @carmstrong: nope, it doesnt show. im using the php_printer.dll for php 5.3, but might not installing properly. any idea?

Comment: What does the php error log show?

Comment: @camstrong: when i tried to call `printer_open` function. it gives me Call to undefined function printer_open()

Comment: http://us.php.net/manual/en/printer.installation.php

Comment: see the path for "Loaded Configuration File" in your php info page. then add extension=php_printer.dll on that php.ini file.
mine, it was in apache folder. but after i added, i got warning that says, `php startup: unable to load dynamic library 'path/to/php_printer.dll' - the specified module cannot be found on wamp`

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't have much experience with installing/enabling extensions myself, this has worked for me in the past:

1. Ensure that `php_printer.dll` is listed under the "ext" directory inside of your PHP installation. If it isn't there, you will need to [download that extension](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php) and save it under the "ext" directory.
2. Add the extension inside of php.ini.
3. Reboot your server and try again.

Hope that helps,
spryno724

Comment: thanks. i tried as you suggestion before. but still not loaded properly. i dont know why. i putted the dll inside php/ext/ folder. then add in php.ini still nope. i header, i need to add in another config(mysql, apached) not to sure. did it work on u before?

Comment: No, since this is a PHP extension you are using, you will only need to configure it inside of php.ini. The thing that tripped me up was the fact that I didn't reboot my server. Try that, then check the phpinfo() to see if PHP recognizes it.

Comment: it still wont work :( .. restarted so many times! i check with `phpinfo()` its not there too. that mean. i need to add that extension in another .ini/.conf

Answer (score 2):

Not

> **extension: php_printer.dll**

You should use

> **extension=php_printer.dll**

Also, be noticed that there are plenty of versions of php_printer.dll and most of them don't work on Windows platform.

Try to get fresh one: [pecl-5.2.6-Win32.zip](http://us.php.net/get/pecl-5.2.6-Win32.zip/from/a/mirror).

Also, consider this line form PHP: Printer manual

> Windows users must enable
>   php_printer.dll inside of php.ini in
>   order to use these functions. A DLL
>   for this PECL extension is currently
>   unavailable.

I've just tried to enable it on Wamp (Windows XP) and it doesn't work.

Comment: i use `=` :) still not loaded? `;extension=php_phar.dll
extension=php_printer.dll
;extension=php_pspell.dll`

Comment: do you have a ; in front of the extension name? the ; will disable that extension, so remove it to enable it.

Comment: @spryno: i removed the `;` from that extension to enable it!

Comment: @boyee007, look at [this topic](http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=268025.0)... Looks like there are a lot of problems with php_printer.dll with Windows.

Comment: @Wh1T3: tried that one, but they said, i must use the version 5.3 as im using php v 3

Comment: that mean i need to downgrade my php version then :(

Answer (score 0):

After enabling the php_printer.dll in your ini, I'd first make sure you did it in the good INI file (by looking at "Loaded Configuration File" in phpinfo()).

Then if proper INI is loaded, but the module still isn't working, I'd go to command prompt  and try running php manually, like 
`php -v`
That will probably give you an error with some more data on the issue - that error wouldn't be visible anywhere through your browser, that is - when you run a page in browser.

In the end - the error that you'll get reported will most probably be that you are trying to load the module which is compiled as '*thread safe*' while your version of PHP was compiled as *non-thread safe*. Or it will be the other way around.
To overcome that, you'll need to download the proper version of PECL. I think that the link mentioned earlier by Wh1T3h4Ck5 is the thread-safe one.

You can try this link:
`http://museum.php.net/php5/pecl-5.2.6-nts-Win32.zip` or maybe here, it's a bunch of win32 binaries:
`http://snaps.php.net/win32/`

After you download that, take the printer dll from it, copy to your c:\php\ext (or whatever you use), reset the web server and it should work.  If it does well, then the `php -v` shouldn't give errors any more. You can also use the `php -m` at that point, to list all the modules loaded, or just check the phpinfo() again.

That was the scenario I had and that's how I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

see the path for "Loaded Configuration File" in your php info page. then add extension=php_printer.dll on that php.ini file. mine, it was "D:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.4\bin\php.ini" at "Loaded Configuration File" on php info page.

after you added, it may give a warning like, `php startup: unable to load dynamic library 'path/to/php_printer.dll' - the specified module cannot be found on wamp`

I got solved this by changing versions of Apache, PHP and MySQL too. correct versions are:
PHP 5.2.6
MySQL 5.0.45
Apache 2.2.9

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use xampp 1.6.8 version it will fix these issues. it has php 5.2.6 and also php_printer.dll file has saved in ext folder in php folder. so you will only have to un-comment the line extension=php_printer.dll in php.ini file which noticed in the path under "Loaded Configuration File" section on php info page. you can find that version of xampp from www.oldapps.com