# PHP to print to a server side printer

Tags: php, apache, dll, printing

I am trying to use PHP to print to a server side printer. I have found similar example code that mostly all use the same API’s functions in order to do this task. When I ran it on my server to test the code it was saying **“PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function printer_open()”**. So I found at least three different versions of the **php_printer.DLL’s**  for this printer function and tried them all separately . I did some more research and looking into the apache server error log found this warning

**PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_printer.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0**

From this found some **Bing search results** that said that the reason it is not loading when apache starts up is because it is depend on other libraries. If this is true I have not as yet been able to find which library DLL’s these are and where to get them. This is what I need help with first to basically know if it is not depended  then why is the PHP warning being thrown or what library’s do I need.

Thanks for any help

zac

I am running a wampserver2.2

Apache 2.4.2

PHP 5.4.3

OS : windows 7 64 bit

Added to the php.ini file

extension=php_printer.dll

and no errors in the php log

also I did restarted the server each time I change the php.ini file or when I put a new DLL in the *ext* directory
I even put the path to the wamp DLL’s  “...\ext\” in the environment variables for windows, as a shot in the dark  .

**Example code**

```
<?php
/* get the sample text */
$lipsum = "test print";//file_get_contents('lipsum.txt');
phpinfo();

/* open a connection to the printer */
$printer = printer_open("Microsoft XPS Document Writer");

/* write the text to the print job */
printer_write($printer, $lipsum);

/* close the connection */
printer_close($printer);
?>
```

3/19/2015 edited

I found this site along with a slightly different error message from the php error log.
basically the below link said the error happened because the PHP_printer.dll is complied with a different visual studio c++  version and therefore need to be recompiled. it gives the steps for the most part I still am tring to get it to work

https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?t=53348&p=204590

Php error:

> [18-Mar-2015 22:55:56 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: printer: Unable
>   to initialize module Module compiled with module API=20121212 PHP
>   compiled with module API=20100525 These options need to match  in
>   Unknown on line 0

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833223/installing-php-printer-on-wamp-server

Comment: you can use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find what dll is missing

Comment: thank you cchacholiades and Lashane I have been looking into your suggestions I will let you both know were this rabbit hole leads me.

Comment: @Lashane When I used the dependency walker to find any missing DLL’s it found a lot . as I found the ones online which I did not have for the  php_printer.dll file. All but a couple I could find where 64 bits. I place them  all for the time being in the EXT\ directory where the php_printer.dll file is. Now the dependency walker does not show any more needed dlls for the php_printer.dll. but I place so many I need to use the dependency walker program to check each of the new dlls to make sure they are ok.

Comment: This process is getting tedious and I am not even sure this is going to fix the problem. I still am getting the **bold
Fatal error: Call to undefined function printer_open() in C:\... \printTest.php bold**
Error when I run it in the browser.  I also get some error from the apache log file but on a good note it does not say anymore that I am unable to load the dynamic library php_printer.dll . but even though it kinda seems the php_printer.dll my  be loaded then why does it not show when using the phpinfo() as a module as well as giving me the fatal error above.

Comment: I also have some apache errors:  **bold PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: printer: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20121212\nPHP    compiled with module API=20100525\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0 bold**                              PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'php5ts.dll' in Unknown on line 0**bold
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/… /ext/dcomp.dll' - A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.\r\n in Unknown on line 0 bold**

Comment: @cchacholiades  I found some more info on this question and updated it above thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case you couldn't found a solution yet....

First of all check in `phpinfo()` that in the version of wmap server you are using thread safety is enabled or not. Just `ctrl+F` in the `phpinfo()` for "thread safety".

Probably thread safety is enabled in the version you are using. Then you have to download the ts(thread safe) version of the `php_printer.dll` which you can find here....

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/printer/0.1.0-dev/

download specific file according to your system requirement (OS and others) and copy it in the extension directory of the wamp. Then just enable the extension in the `php.ini` file like

```
extension=php_printer.dll
```

just add this line in the ini file if already not there and there will be no `;` at the beginning.

Hope it helps ...