# Laravel print to printer

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to add the printer extension to laravel. But I don't know how to do this while using Laravel. It says that I have to add the php_printer.dll to php.ini. But I use Laravel. Does anyone know how I can add this extension to Laravel?

Link:
http://php.net/manual/fa/book.printer.php

Update:
I added the extension in the ext map but now it says that it can not be found
I get the following error:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_printer.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_printer.dll (The specified module could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_printer.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_printer.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_printer.dll (The specified module could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_printer.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
Laravel development server started: http://127.0.0.1:8000
[Wed Sep  5 14:37:23 2018] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_printer.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_printer.dll (The specified module could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_printer.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: And Laravel uses PHP. I'd guess you'd need "_to add the php_printer.dll to php.ini_".

Comment: What do you mean? there is no php.ini file in Laravel

Comment: You need to have `PHP` installed to run Laravel, right? If so, there's at least one `php.ini`.

Comment: I get an error after I added it

Comment: That means that your system can't find the DLL.

Comment: I added this: extension=php_printer.dll

Answer (score 1):

Lets first get the terms right.

The extension you are adding isn't a laravel extension.  It is a PHP extension.  Laravel is a framework that is written in PHP.

You can not just add the directive into the php.ini file and expect it to work.  You also need to install the files.  In this case you need to get them from [PECL](http://pecl.php.net/).

The question of how to install is already asked and answereed here [installing php_printer on wamp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833223/installing-php-printer-on-wamp-server)

Comment: I just looked at the man page at php.net

It clearly states that a DLL for this PECL extention is not available.  You will need to compile it from scatch.

Comment: Some further investigation and it looks like this in an ancient extension - possibly no longer supported.  I would suggest you look for something more up to date.

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately I didn't found another solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XAMPP, open it up and click on apache->config, you can find php.ini there.